# Why does the replicate function (rep) not return nested lists when given a list as input?

Tags: r

I don't understand why both the following commands produce the same output:

```
rep(list(rnorm(2)), 2) %>% str
list(rnorm(2), rnorm(2)) %>% str
```

```
List of 2
 $ : num [1:2] 0.207 -0.293
 $ : num [1:2] 0.207 -0.293

List of 2
 $ : num [1:2] 0.0342 -1.1086
 $ : num [1:2] 2.186 -0.165
```

Shouldn't the first command produce a "meta-list" containing two lists which contain each a numeric vector? Because I'm telling the replicate function: "Replicate the list containing a numeric vector two times". So why does it only replicate the content of the list two times, but not the list itself?

And to build on this: How would I create a "meta-list" which is replicating one list n number of times?

Comment: Do you want `replicate(2, list(rnorm(2)), simplify=FALSE)` instead?

Comment: Yes! This is what I expected ```rep(list(rnorm(2)), 2) %>% str``` would do. Why does ```rep()``` produce a different output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this makes sense, so I'll try to explain my understanding.
Each part of your repeated output should be equal to the original object, right?

Let's confirm this with a simple example:

```
x <- 5
r <- rep(x,2)
identical(r[1], x)
##[1] TRUE
identical(r[2], x)
##[1] TRUE
```

Then with a `list` like your example:

```
x <- list(rnorm(2))
r <- rep(x,2)
identical(r[1], x)
##[1] TRUE
identical(r[2], x)
##[1] TRUE
```

Now with a more complex example of an embedded list like you want:

```
xl <- list(rnorm(2))
x <- list(xl)
## above line is equivalent to x <- list(list(rnorm(2)))
r <- rep(x,2)
identical(r[1], x)
##[1] TRUE
identical(r[2], x)
##[1] TRUE
```

Or use `replicate` as an alternative if you want to use the simple list as input instead:

```
identical(r, replicate(2, xl, simplify=FALSE) )
##[1] TRUE
```